# DROP TYPE causes SYNONYM Errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to change a user defined type from a VARCHAR(15) to a VARCHAR(20) in a database with many tables, views, procedures, functions, and synonyms.  I initially thought I could just use one line - something like `ALTER TYPE`, but this is instead a very complicated task.

I'm currently trying the workaround found here: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/319134/msft-mso-support-alter-type 
However, that script doesn't account for table synonyms, so when the `DROP TYPE` line is executed, I get the following error: **Cannot alter 'MY_SYNONYM' because it is not a table.**

I tried modifying the script to drop all synonyms, but then when `DROP TYPE` line is executed, I get this error: **Cannot find the object "MY_SYNONYM" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.**

I realize there are plenty of workaround scripts out there that deal with resizing a VARCHAR user defined type, but none of them seem to work in my situation.  But I feel like I'm so close with this one.

Comment: What are the exact commands you are trying to execute?

Comment: @Joe W The workaround that I'm using (see the connect.microsoft link) basically removes all references to the type, drops the type, recreates the type with the new size, and then recreates all the references.  The line that causes the errors is `DROP TYPE MY_SCHEMA.udt_MY_TYPE`.

Comment: It's usually around about this time that most people realise that, however promising the concept may appear, UDTs in SQL Server are just more hassle than they're worth (I usually make an exception for UD-Table-Types, but even with them you have to drop and re-create if you want to change them).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're exactly right.